# Can't build project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, glut

I am programming in Eclipse C++ OpenGL using MinGW.

My project was running well before I have done this: -

```
Right-click on the the project and select "Properties"
Navigate to C/C++ Build -> Settings
Select the Tool Settings tab.
Navigate to GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous
In the option setting labeled Other Flags add -std=c++11
```

I did it because I had to use vector arrays in my code.

Problem is that now I can't build my project. When I click build, it builds 100% showing no error but produces no .exe file.

Edit: =
Solution.

Putting a space when appending **-std=c++11** to command-line.

Comment: What version of mingw-gcc is it? Does removing `-std=c++11` fix the problem?

Comment: @greatwolf Yes, removing -std=c++11 and changing the lines where I used vector arrays to simple fixed size.

vector<GLfloat> cone1 { 0.0f, 2.4f, -11.0f, /*rotated*/30.0f, -1.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

to

GLfloat cone1[] = { 0.0f, 2.4f, -11.0f, /*rotated*/30.0f, -1.5, 0.0, 0.0 };

Comment: Why can't you use vectors without adding that flag? Are you including <vector>?

Comment: @GCC404 Yes I have included. But without flag it says (this)[http://sphotos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/999017_3104347665314_295266663_n.jpg]

Comment: I think in C++98 you can't use that constructor for vectors. To create a new vector do it like this:
vector<GLfloat> cone1;
cone1.push_back(0.0f); cone1.push_back(*element here*);

To why it is not compiling C++11, try updating your compiler.

Comment: @GCC404 I updated MinGW to latest one but couldn't resolve.

Comment: @GCC404 I chose to use vectors because I wanted to write minimum lines of code(at the time when I wanted to update cells of array with my desired values).

Comment: Well, you can also create a vector from an array, if that helps.

vector<int> v (array, array+ sizeof(array) / sizeof(GLfloat) );

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33079/discussion-between-umair-ayub-and-gcc404)

Comment: You still haven't state what version of gcc this is being done with. Keep in mine mingw-gcc 4.6.3 and earlier doesn't support `-std=c++11`. Maybe Eclipse is silently failing the build without telling you and that's the reason there's no executable?

Comment: @greatwolf I have solved my problem. I did not put space before **-std=c++11** while appending to command-line and I was updating my vector without putting equal sign too. 
Thanks.

Comment: You should add that as an answer to take it off SO's unanswered list.

Answer (score 2):

Putting a space when appending `-std=c++11` to command-line.

And changing

```
 cone1 {1.0f , 2.0f};
```

to

```
cone1 = {1.0f, 2.0f}; //problem fixed after doing this.
```

Note: - I declared my vectors like so

```
vector<GLfloat> cone1{1.0f, 3.0};
```